SQL for hierarchical cumulative sum, but with cumulative sum of child node modified before used to calculate parent's cumsum



entityId
parentId
percentContribution
emission
emission_locationbased
emission_marketbased
cumsum_locationbased
cumsum_marketbased




E1

60
30


60
70


E2
E1
80
20


30
40


E3
E2
80

10
20
10
20



This is a sample of a tree structure in a single table that I'm working on. The table is a hierarchy of entities, each generating a certain amount of emissions. There are three fields relating to the amount of emissions generated by each entity: emission, emission_locationbased, and emission_marketbased. If an entity has a non-null emission value, then its emission_locationbased and emissions_marketbased values are null. If an entity has a null emission value, then it has both an emission_locationbased and emissions_marketbased value.
The issue is taking percentContribution into account. It indicate how many percentage of that entity's cumulative emission (both _locationbased and _marketbased) that node contribute to its parent's cumulative sum.
For example:



entityId
parentId
percentContribution
emission
emission_locationbased
cumsum_locationbased_percent




E1

60
30

(28*80/100) + 30 = 52.4


E2
E1
80
20

(10 * 80/100) + 20 = 28


E2
E2
80

10
10



This is how I calculated cumsum_locationbased and cumsum_marketbased:
WITH base_data AS (
    SELECT 
        entityId,
        parentId,
        emission,
        emission_locationbased ,
        emissions_marketbased ,
        array_agg(entityId) OVER (ORDER BY parentId) AS arr
    FROM entity
),

cumulative_sums AS (
    SELECT
        entityId,
        parentId,
        emission,
        emission_locationbased ,
        emissions_marketbased ,
        SUM(COALESCE(emission, emission_locationbased , 0)) 
            OVER (ORDER BY arr)  AS cumsum_locationbased, 
        SUM(COALESCE(emission, emissions_marketbased , 0)) 
            OVER (ORDER BY arr) AS cumsum_marketbased  
    FROM base_data
    GROUP BY entityId, parentId, emission, emission_locationbased, emissions_marketbased, arr
)

SELECT
    entityId,
    parentId,
    emission,
    CASE WHEN emission IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE emission_locationbased END AS emission_locationbased ,
    CASE WHEN emission IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE emissions_marketbased END AS emissions_marketbased,
    cumsum_locationbased,
    cumsum_marketbased
FROM cumulative_sums

I has been a while since I last touch SQL so I can't figure out what to do.

Which DBMS is this?

@Charlieface I'm making queries to a DynamoDB table via Athena
